# Daily values to Monthly Means for Multiple Years Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, time-series

I have observed daily data that I need to compare to generated Monthly data so I need to get a mean of each month over the thirty year period.

My observed data set is currently in 365x31 with rows being each day (no leap years!) and the extra column being the month number (1-12).

the problem I am having is that I can only seem to get a script to get the mean of all years. ie. I cannot figure how to get the script to do it for each column separately. Example of the data is below:

```
1    12    14
1    -15   10
2    13    3
2    2     37
...all the way to 12 for 365 rows
```

SO: to recap, I need to get the mean of [12; -15; 13; 2] then [14; 10; 3; 37] and so on.

I have been trying to use the unique() function to loop through which works for getting the number rows to average but incorrect means. Now I need it to do each month(28-31 rows) and column individually. Result should be a 12x30 matrix. I feel like I am missing something SIMPLE. Code:

```
u = unique(m); %get unique values of m (months) ie) 1-12

for i=1:length(u)
   month(i) = mean(obatm(u(i), (2:31)); % the average for each month of each year
end
```

Appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Comment: So I fail to understand, what's wrong with applying `mean` on your data? What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: mean(A) will just give me the whole column, I need it to stop after each month. That is what I was attempting from that code. But like I said, something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter the rows for each month and then apply `mean`, like so:

```
month = zeros(12, size(obatm, 2));
for k = 1:12
    month(k, :) = mean(obatm(obatm(:, 1) == k, :));
end
```

**EDIT:**
If you want something fancy, you can also do this:

```
cols = size(obatm, 2) - 1;
subs = bsxfun(@plus, obatm(:, 1), (0:12:12 * (cols - 1)));
vals = obatm(:, 2:end);
month = reshape(accumarray(subs(:), vals(:), [12 * cols, 1], @mean), 12, cols)
```

*Look, Ma, no loops!*

Comment: Worked great, thank you! I will go read about filtering a bit more.